# COUNTIF with variable columns

Tags: excel, match, countif

I have a table that consists of workstations and the software installed on them. It looks something like...

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>endpoint</th><th>software1 v3</th><th>software1 v4</th><th>software2</th><th>software3</th></tr><tr><td>Workstation1 </td><td>x</td><td> </td><td>x</td><td>x</td></tr><tr><td>Workstation2</td><td>x</td><td> </td><td>x</td><td>x</td></tr><tr><td>Workstation3</td><td> </td><td>x</td><td>x</td><td>x</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Software1 exists on multiple machines but in multiple different versions.  I am looking to sum all of the columns that match the software name - The version isn't important at the moment. In this test data I would want the final output to tell me that Software1 exists on 3 machines even though it's two different versions.

I imagine it's a combination of SUM with COUNTIF and INDEX/MATCH but I haven't quite figured out the combination yet.

This gets me to the number of columns I need to SUM: =SUM(COUNTIF(Tbl[#All], "*" & A2 & "*"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming A2 contains Software1, it looks like you want:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(Tbl[#Headers],LEN(A2))=A2)*(Tbl="x"))
```

Comment: That did it.  I'm going to need to review this answer a bit because the use of LEN is throwing me off.  I don't know why it worked, only that it did.

In any case, thank you for the quick response!

Comment: The `LEN` is just there to determine how many characters the `LEFT` formula should return.